# Java Concurrency synchronization issue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Can any one explain why the below code will cause race condition as I make the method synchronized but its object level locking, I am following the java concurrency in depth.
Please explain because if I use class level it will definitely work, I doubt that the lock occupied by the thread is different for each.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package lession2.shared.object;

/**
 * @author so_what
 *
 */

class SharedClass {
    private static int sharedData;

    public synchronized   int getSharedData() {
        return sharedData;
    }

    public synchronized   void setSharedData(int sharedData) {

        SharedClass.sharedData = sharedData;
    }

}

//output of the program should be the distinct numbers
public class StaleDataExample extends Thread {
    static  SharedClass s1=new SharedClass();
    static  int counter=0;
    public static  void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        StaleDataExample t1=new StaleDataExample();
        StaleDataExample t2=new StaleDataExample();
        StaleDataExample t3=new StaleDataExample();
        StaleDataExample t4=new StaleDataExample();
        StaleDataExample t5=new StaleDataExample();
        StaleDataExample t6=new StaleDataExample();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        t5.start();
        t6.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();
        t6.join();
        System.out.println();

    }
    public void run()
    {

        s1.setSharedData(s1.getSharedData()+1); //read->modify->write operation
        System.out.print(s1.getSharedData()+" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: `//read->modify->write operation` only the `read` and `write` are synchronized (independently). Should be a single atomic operation.

Comment: can you please justify why the get and set operation are not acquiring the same lock because if they acquiring the same lock composite atomicity will be achieved.

Comment: They _are_ acquiring the same lock. "because if they acquiring the same lock composite atomicity will be achieved" No it won't, there is still a timeslice where you modify the value which is not synchronized at all, where other threads can intervene.

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you aren't incrementing the shared value in an atomic (e.g. synchronized) way.

Let's examine the following line:

```
s1.setSharedData(s1.getSharedData()+1)
```

First, you call `getSharedData`, which is `synchronized. You then increment the value, at call`setSharedData` to set the new value. The problem is that the program could context-switch between the get and the set. Consider the following example:

1. Thread #1 calls `getSharedData()`, and get 0
2. Thread #2 calls `getSharedData()`, and also gets 0
3. Thread #1 adds 1 to its value, and calls `setSharedData(1)`.
4. Thread #2 also adds 1 to its value, and calls `setSharedData(1)`, instead of `setSharedData(2)` that you would expect.

One way to solve such problems is not to allow the class' user to set the value directly, but provide them with a method to atomically increment the value:

```
class SharedClass {
    private static int sharedData;

    public synchronized int getSharedData() {
        return sharedData;
    }

    public synchronized void incrementSharedData(int amount) {
        sharedData += amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh I missed that one so other solution is to use the AtomicInteger to prevent the race condition here.
Also you are doing the calculation in synchronized method that will also work.



class SharedClass {
 private  AtomicInteger sharedData=new AtomicInteger(0);

 public synchronized   int getSharedData() {
  return sharedData.getAndIncrement();
 }

 

}


 public void run()
 {
 
 
 System.out.print(s1.getSharedData()+" ");
 }

}